# Calling the same order of functions in C with one changing function each time. How to implement more elegantly?

Tags: c, function

I have the following code calling three different functions named `func_a`, `func_b` and `func_c`, which are using the same parameter. Before and after each call I need to call the functions `foo` and `bar` in order to reset/print some variables. Both are doing the same thing every time I call them.

```
foo();
func_a(param);
bar();

foo();
func_b(param);
bar();

foo();
func_c(param);
bar();
```

So, my question: is there any way to make this part more elegant? In my case it is going up to `func_e`, so I have five near repeats of this code.

Comment: can't you use a single for loop - five times or param is going to be different each time?? {question is unclear}

Comment: Define *elegant* in this context? What you have here is about as verbose and uncomplicated as you can get. Are you looking for some elaborate solution to repeat this idea (`foo() someFunction() bar()`) for some arbitrary large N number of distinct functions ? If not, if you only need the three, keep this.

Comment: It seems u are trying to implement/use instrumentation/profile !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you can put all the things that are in common into a single function that invokes a function pointer. Then iterate over an array of function pointers, passing them into the single helper function:

```
void invoke_foo_func_bar (void (*func)(int), int param) {
    foo();
    func(param);
    bar();
}

/* ... */
void (*funcs[])(int) = { func_a, func_b, func_c };
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(funcs)/sizeof(*funcs); ++i) {
    invoke_foo_func_bar(funcs[i], param);
}
```